# Wordpress Jetpack Plugin simple_payments issue

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

I just updated the jetpack wordpress plugin, and this error happened:

```
Fatal Error (E_ERROR): Call to undefined method Jetpack_Simple_Payments::is_enabled_jetpack_simple_payments() occurred in wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/widgets/simple-payments.php on line 480 please make sure that your website is accessible
```

Does any one has any approach about a solution? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

for the time being you can add the missing method **is_enabled_jetpack_simple_payments** in the file: 
jetpack/modules/simple-payments/simple-payments.php

```
function is_enabled_jetpack_simple_payments() {
    /**
     * Can be used by plugin authors to disable the conflicting output of Simple Payments.
     *
     * @since 6.3.0
     *
     * @param bool True if Simple Payments should be disabled, false otherwise.
     */
    if ( apply_filters( 'jetpack_disable_simple_payments', false ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    // For WPCOM sites
    if ( defined( 'IS_WPCOM' ) && IS_WPCOM && function_exists( 'has_blog_sticker' ) ) {
        $site_id = $this->get_blog_id();
        return has_blog_sticker( 'premium-plan', $site_id ) || has_blog_sticker( 'business-plan', $site_id );
    }
    // For all Jetpack sites
    return Jetpack::is_active() && Jetpack::active_plan_supports( 'simple-payments');
}
```